# Receiving an "Unknown function" error in Puppet

Tags: puppet

Receiving an error when defining a function in Puppet. `C:\Windows\system32>  puppet agent --test --server davidhromyk.test.5.puppet.lrscorp.net --masterport 8937 --ssldir C:\Temp\davidhromyk.test.5.puppet.lrscorp.net
Info: Using configured environment 'internal'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'driver_name'. (file: /home/david.hromyk/.puppetlabs/etc/code/environments/internal/modules/windows_print_server/manifests/init.pp, line: 12, column: 41) on node ops-dev-print01.lrscorp.net
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run`

This is my module configuration.

```
class windows_print_server (
  $printers,
  ){

  exec { 'Install-PrintServices':
    command  => 'Install-WindowsFeature -Name @("print-services","Print-LPD-Service")',
    unless   => '& { exit ((Get-WindowsFeature -Name Print-Services).installed -eq $false) }',
    provider => powershell,
  }

$printers.each |Integer $index, Hash $printer| {
 exec { "add printer driver ${printer.driver_name} for ${printer.name}":
  command => "Add-PrinterDriver -Name ${printer.driver_name}",
  unless  => "Get-PrinterDriver -Name ${printer.driver_name}",
}
exec { "add printer port $printer.port_name for ${printer.name}":
  command => "Add-PrinterPort -Name ${printer.port_name}",
  unless  => "Get-PrinterPort -Name ${printer.port.name}",
}
exec { "add printer $$printer.name for $printer.name":
  command => "Add-Printer -Name ${printer.name}",
  unless  => "Get-Printer -Name ${printer.name}",
  }
 }
}
```

Here is my Hiera configuration.

```
{
  "classes": [
   "windows_print_server"
  ],
  "windows_server::administrators::list": ["ops-security"],
  "windows_print_server::printers": [
    {"name": "Bldg2-Flr1-HPM426fdn", "port_name": "172.17.17.132", "driver_name": "HP Color LaserJet Pro M452 PCL 6"},
    {"name": "Bldg3-Flr 4 Dell 2335dn", "port_name": "172.17.33.174", "driver_name": "Dell 2335dn MFP PCL6"}
  ]
}
```

I believe that somewhere I am missing proper syntax on init.pp for ${printer.driver_name}. Not sure of the proper way to go about it. Something along the lines of ${printer[“name”]}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The syntax for accessing values from a hash](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_data_hash.html#accessing-values) uses the square bracket operator `[]` around the key:

```
$printer['driver_name']
```

Under most circumstances, the quotes around the key are optional, as Puppet recognizes bare words as strings (this is a general characteristic of the Puppet language, not specific to hash keys).

To interpolate the value into a string, you need to enclose everything but the `$` in curly braces:

```
$printers.each |Integer $index, Hash $printer| {
 exec { "add printer driver ${printer[driver_name]} for ${printer[name]}":
  command => "Add-PrinterDriver -Name ${printer[driver_name]}",
  unless  => "Get-PrinterDriver -Name ${printer[driver_name]}",
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was extremely helpful! I do however run into this error afterwards.
`Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter unless failed on Exec[add printer driver HP Color LaserJet Pro M452 PCL 6 for Bldg2-Flr1-HPM426fdn]: 'Get-PrinterDriver -Name HP Color LaserJet Pro M452 PCL 6' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path. (file: /home/david.hromyk/.puppetlabs/etc/code/environments/internal/modules/windows_print_server/manifests/init.pp, line: 12)`

Comment: @DavidHromyk, with regard to the new error, the associated diagnostic message already tells you what to do: use the full paths to your commands in the `unless` and `command` properties of your `Exec`, or else add a `path` property that includes the appropriate path.